# How to save value from a selected checkbox to a file using php?

Tags: php, html, css, file, checkbox

My text file is as follow:

> 12345 234 455
>   23 67 9666 13 56
>   1234 777 900

whenever I'm checking the preferred check-boxes only the first value of each line appear other value does not appear ,I mean like for the first line only 12345 is appearing and 234 455 don't appear ;
Does any one help me?
I need whenever I'm selecting any check boxes the complete line contain should be selected or appearing as well

process.php

```
require 'connect.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['check']) && ! empty($_POST['check']))  
{
    $check=$_POST['check'];
    $numberOfCheck=count($check);

    echo ("You have checked $numberOfCheck checkboxes : ");

    for ($i=0; $i<$numberOfCheck; $i++)  
    {
        echo '<br>';
        echo ($check[$i]. " ");

        $VarCheck=$check[$i];
        $name=time();
        $myFile=fopen($name,"a");
        $txt=$VarCheck;

        fwrite($myFile,$txt);
        fclose($myFile);    
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Zero check selected";
}


?>
```

This is my dynamic table generating according to the number of line of my file text

```
<?php

echo '<form method="POST" action="process.php">';

$file = fopen("text.txt","r");

echo '<table border="1">';

while(! feof($file))

  {

  $data= fgets($file);

echo '<tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value='.$data.'</td>

<td>'.$data.'</td></tr>';


  }
fclose($file);

echo '<input type="submit" value="send">';

echo '</form>';

?>
```

Comment: For checkboxes you usually use one name per box. `isset($_POST['check'])` tells if it is checked.

Comment: In general you may want to use consistent variable naming.  Your $VarCheck variable doesn't match the rest of your camelCasing and it also isn't actually used in the function you have outlined above (you can cut it out and where you insert $txt you could just insert $check[$i].

Comment: this my dynamic table generating according to my file text line                                                                                                                   h                                                                      

<?php

echo '<form method="POST" action="process.php">';
$file = fopen("text.txt","r");

echo '<table border="1">';
while(! feof($file))
  {
  $data= fgets($file);

echo '<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value='.$data.'</td>

<td>'.$data.'</td></tr>';

  }
fclose($file);

echo '<input type="submit" value="send">';
echo '</form>';

?>

Comment: code in comment is very hard to read, edit the question and add it

Comment: Do learn how to indent code! I'm not going to do this again.

Comment: please ,i need any help from your side!!

Comment: Seems to have worked for me. However, if you mean that it shows as `You have checked 3 checkboxes :
12345
23
1234` after clicking submit and chosen all 3 checkboxes, then that's all I can see.

Comment: i'm generating a dynamic table along with checkboxes associated to each row ,the content of the table will be fetch from my text file then i need whenever i selectind any checkbox the content should be save to another text file

Comment: Fred-ii , i do have checkbox according to the number of line of my text file as the matter of the fact my file has 3 line                                      "12345 234 455" first line
"23 67 9666 13 56" second line
"1234 777 900" third line

Comment: does anyone help me?

Comment: See Adrian's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget close (`>`) your input tag and set the `"` for the input value.

You must change this line:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value='.$data.'</td>
```

to:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$data.'"></td>
```

**EDIT** Test with this:

> File text.txt

```
12345 234 455
23 67 9666 13 56
1234 777 900
```

> Page 1.php

```
<?php

echo '<form method="POST" action="process.php">';

$file = fopen("text.txt","r");

echo '<table border="1">';

while(! feof($file))

  {

  $data= fgets($file);

if(trim($data) != '') {
echo '<tr>

<td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$data.'"></td>

<td>'.$data.'</td></tr>';
}

  }
fclose($file);

echo '<input type="submit" value="send">';

echo '</form>';

?>
```

> Page process.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['check']) && ! empty($_POST['check']))  
{
    $check=$_POST['check'];
    $numberOfCheck=count($check);

    echo ("You have checked $numberOfCheck checkboxes : ");

    for ($i=0; $i<$numberOfCheck; $i++)  
    {
        echo '<br>';
        echo ($check[$i]. " ");

        $VarCheck=$check[$i];
        $name=time();
        $myFile=fopen($name,"a");
        $txt=$VarCheck;

        fwrite($myFile,$txt);
        fclose($myFile);    
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Zero check selected";
}


?>
```

Comment: yes ,i made the change to by closing(>) .still is not working

Comment: @israkany change the whole line because you must put into ' ' $data

Comment: Adrian Cid   ;;;sorry i should said it was working ,i'm sorry ,i was mistaken ,it's working,thanks...thanks

Comment: @israkany don't forget check the answer as correct ;-)

Comment: -(Adrian cid  -- thanks ,i 've checked has correct ,still have another issues ,i need to convert my array content as string $Var=string implode($check[$i]) unfortunately it's not show me the correct output ,can you heplp me ? or should i post it as another question? thanks

Comment: @israkany I think that is better post another question